# Why the value are not reflecting in the service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, static, app-config

App.Config

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="maxDiscount" value="25"/>
 </appSettings>
```

This is my CustomerConfig.cs

```
    public class CustomerConfig
    {
    private static int GetValue(string key)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]);
    }

    public static int MaxDiscount
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue("maxDiscount");
        }
  }
```

Service Class

```
 public class CustomerService : ICustomer
{
    private readonly int _maxDiscount;

    public CustomerService() 
    {
        //the value is NOT reflecting here
        _maxDiscount = CustomerConfig.MaxDiscount;
        //watching at this line I see _maxDiscount = 0
    }
}
```

**Note:-**
All these above class are in the same layer (Class Library project) 
While the below controller is in another layer (UI Layer)

MVC Controller.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
 private readonly int _maxDiscount;
 public SomeController() 
        : base()
    {
        //here the value 25 is reflecting
         _maxDiscount = CustomerConfig.MaxDiscount;
    }
}
```

Why the value of maxDiscount is not reflecting in the service layer??

> What is causing this & how do I fetch the value in the service layer??

Comment: What does it mean `value not reflecting`? Service class and CustomConfig class part of the same project? Wher app.config is located? Aren't you able to get the value configured in web.config?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Service class ,CustomConfig & App.Config are all part of same project while SomeController is another layer(UI layer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager` will load the configuration from the executing assembly config file. In your scenario it will be the `web.config` file.

If you want that to work you should add that setting in your `web.config` file or, you really want to go that way, you could try using [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) but I don't know if that's a good idea (or if it works with dlls).

Comment: Yes.just checked, your statments seems true. Thank you :)